# Remove app names in OS X Yosemite Dock

Tags: macos, dock

How can I disable/hide the App Name in the OS X Yosemite Dock?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`.

You need to replace every label like `"file-label" => "AppName"` with `"file-label" => ""`.

Restart the Dock or logout and back again to activate the changes.

Comment: This only works for applications you actually drag into the Dock, not for applications which only show up in the Dock while running.

Comment: In that file i only see:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>DesktopAdminImageGenerationNumber</key>
 <dict>
  <key>GenerationNumber</key>
  <string>2</string>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: How did you open the file?

Comment: I used textWrangler app

Comment: Could you test if `plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` shows you other result that TextWrangler?